# Keep Json bigger than 12MB in client side

Tags: javascript, html

I have a free search engine on my website.

I want to keep all search terms and their data on the client side (to improve search speed).

I get the data by an ajax call as a json object.

The size of the json is greater than 12MB, so I can not keep it in local storage because it can not contain such large data.

How can I keep the data on the client side?

Thanks.

Comment: If the space is available you can use `requestFileSystem` at Chromium, Chrome

Comment: That's quite of a bit of data to keep client-side. How long are your remote calls taking that makes keeping 12MB locally more feasible?

Comment: I think you are approaching this wrong - if you are concerned about speed, loading a >12MB json is not a good start. Try to offload the searching to the server

Comment: You should not store this amount on the client side. Try to fetch data from the server on request.

Comment: You can use `indexeddb` - it supports up to 50mb on desktop, but only 5 on mobile. In addition it's an async object graph db, which will make search really easy.

Comment: @Tor - The search speed increases tenfold when I save data in the client side and does not do an ajax request on each search.

Comment: @JakubJudas: I'm taking the data >12MB only once from the server, and then keeping it in the client side for a very long time(update the data only seldom).

Comment: @OriDrori: Thanks, but my site is a responsive website, and it's also used on desktop and mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

It is not a right idea to keep that big data on the client's local storage. Local storage size changes from browser to browser. Even some browsers give more than 5MB, for example, Opera gives 3MB in max.

The better choice would be to cache the search data at the backend but to cache a small amount of data on the client. When the user enters keys on the search box, you can bring data starts with let's say with 3 characters and cache on the client only that data. But again, it should be deleted after was used.

Comment: Thanks. the explanation why not to use in local storage is great. for the second question - why do i need to delete the data after was used? and  any other idea how to keep tha date in the client, but not in local storage? like in js file/json file something?